# Wpf Bing api & Pushpin

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps, eventhandler, pushpin

Question about bing api Wpf sdk and c#...

I'm using this code to create and place PushPins on my map.
But...  ClickOnPushpin EventHandler is not working...

```
    private void AddPushPin(IpInfo nfo)
    {
        double lat = Convert.ToDouble(nfo.dLat,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        double lon = Convert.ToDouble(nfo.dLong, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        pin.Location = new Location(lat, lon);

        pin.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ClickOnPushpin);

        MyMap.Center = pin.Location;
        MyMap.Children.Add(pin);
    }

    private void ClickOnPushpin(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //DoWhateverYouWant
    }
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Is not working in which way? There is no code in the event handler.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Because `ClickOnPushpin()` is just empty.

Comment: Yes, i know is empty, I just delete the content to cut down the post. I've placed a breakpoint at the ClicOnPushpin code and it never hits...

Comment: Wonferful... there is a MouseDown event on the map itself that is blocking the pushpin eventhandler... removing it from the xaml fixed the issue... Now i have to deal with this because i need both eventhandlers... :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code as is and it worked in the WPF map control. The mouse events on the map wouldn't cause any issue here. I've been using this method of adding click events to pushpin sin the WPF map control for years.